# How to process fetched data in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I try to proces data come from api then use it to render, but I always go to a problem with async because the process function doesn't wait for my fetching functions.

```js
const [fetchData1, setData1] = useState([]);
const [fetchData1, setData2] = useState([]);
const [processedData, setProcessedData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 const getData1 = async () => {
  //get data1 using axios
  //setData1(response)
 }
 const getData2 = async () => {
  //get data2 using axios
  //setData2(response)
 }
 getData1();
 getData2();
 setProcessedData(processData(fetchData1, fetchData2));
}, [])

const processData = (data1, data2) => {
 //process two data
 //return data;
}
```

Even when I try to wrap two fetching functions and the process function in an async function but the problem remains the same.

```js
(async () => {
  await getData1();
  await getData2();
  setProcessedData(processData(fetchData1, fetchData2));
})
```

Comment: `useEffect` is a bit quirky combined with `async`. I recommend reading this: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data to understand exactly how to use helper functions

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put processData function inside the setProcessData when making the question, edited.

Comment: Improve the language (code) of the question this is too hard to read ..  where is `processData` called ??

Comment: @Phil - I missed it at first, too. :-) It's in the call to `setProcessedData`: `setProcessedData(processData(fetchData1, fetchData2));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question, as far as I can tell you don't need `fetchData1` and `fetchData2`, you just want the `processedData`. The problem with your current code is that it's using the default values of `fetchData1` and `fetchData2` when calling `setProcessedData`, it's not using the results form axios.

Wait for both promises to settle and use their results. See comments:

```
const [processedData, setProcessedData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const getData1 = async () => {
        //get data1 using axios
        //setData1(response)
    };
    const getData2 = async () => {
        //get data2 using axios
        //setData2(response)
    };
    // *** Wait for both promises to be fulfilled
    Promise.all(
        getData1(),
        getData2()
    ).then([data1, data2]) => { // Get those results into parameters
        // *** Use the parameter values
        setProcessedData(processData(data1, data2));
    }).catch(error => {
        // handle/report error
    });
}, []);

// *** render using the current values in `processedData`
```

Note that since you're **only** do this when the component is first created, you don't need to worry about cancelling it, etc., when other state in the component changes (if it has other state). If the calls depended on other state data you were listing in the dependency array, you might need to handle disregarding earlier results if that other data changed during the calls to axios. But again, not with what you're doing here.

Answer (score -1):

`Promise.all` is for handling multiple asnyc operations:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Here is more examples:

https://www.taniarascia.com/promise-all-with-async-await/

Comment: that's not really the issue, though. It's more using helper functions inside `useEffect` in React

Comment: The problem is that setProcessedData needs to be run after 2 api calls are finished. That  is what `Promise.all` is.

Comment: not quite, `Promise.all` just runs the promises concurrently. Doing two `await` statements in a row has the same effect, but they are run sequentially. But again, I think the issue is that they are running inside `useEffect`, which has its own quirks